# print_req_error I/O error on Ubuntu server 18.04 Mysql Install

Tags: server, 18.04, mysql, hyper-v

I keep getting 
 print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
whenever i attempt to install MYSQL on my newly installed Ubuntu server.

Not sure if it has anything to do with the server being a HyperV cluster running from a VHD?

This is super annoying, I've reinstalled Ubuntu many times and i always get this dam error.
After installing MYSQL i'm not getting any prompt to set a password probably because the install is corrupted from this error?

Has anyone experienced this before?